# Estimating the length of a curve from below by a bound on its curvature.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, curvature

I got stuck on a problem. Let $\alpha(s)$ be smooth simple closed curve  with curvature $k(s)$ and $0 <k(s) \leq c $. Then show that the length of the curve is limited from below by $2\pi \frac{1}{c}$. I can't formalize the solution very well: in a neighborhood of each point $\alpha(s)$ the curve $\alpha$ has length very near to the length of the osculating circle tangent at $\alpha(s),$ and the osculating circle has radius at least $\frac{1}{c},$ then we should be able to conclude by summing up all the local contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That follows from a simple interpretation of $k$ that you may or may not know.

Let $ \alpha: [0,L] \to \mathbb R^2$ be the arc-length parametrization of the simple closed curve. Then

$$L = \operatorname{length of }\alpha= \int_0^L  dt \ge \frac{1}{c} \int_0^L k(t) dt. $$

Since $\alpha$ has arc length parametrization, $\alpha'(t) = (\cos \theta(t), \sin\theta(t))$, where $\theta$ is the angle $c$ make with the $x$-axis. Thus

$$ k(t) = \alpha''(t) \cdot n(t) = \theta'(t). $$

Hence

$$\int_0^L k(t)dt = \theta(L) - \theta(0).$$

Since $\alpha$ is a simple closed curve, the winding number is 1. Thus $\theta(L) - \theta(0) = 2\pi$, which implies that

$$ L \ge \frac{2\pi}{c}.$$